# EditText hint is not animating

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-transitions

In my app, I am using Android Activity Slide transition, which contained within an InputTextLayout.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:hint="First Name "/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Activity enter from window resource transition-v21/profile_enter.xml

```
<transitionSet 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:transitionOrdering="together"
    android:duration="400"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/linear_out_slow_in">

    <slide android:slideEdge="right">
        <targets>
            <target android:excludeId="@android:id/navigationBarBackground"/>
            <target android:excludeId="@android:id/statusBarBackground" />
        </targets>
    </slide>

    <fade android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime">
        <targets>
            <target android:targetId="@android:id/navigationBarBackground" />
            <target android:targetId="@android:id/statusBarBackground" />
        </targets>
    </fade>

</transitionSet>
```

Activity return from window resource transition-v21/profile_return.xml

```
<transitionSet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:transitionOrdering="together"
android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_linear_in">

<slide
    android:slideEdge="bottom"
    android:duration="300">

    <targets>
        <target android:excludeId="@android:id/navigationBarBackground" />
        <target android:excludeId="@android:id/statusBarBackground" />
    </targets>

</slide>

<fade
    android:startDelay="200"
    android:duration="200">
    <targets>
        <target android:targetId="@id/toolbar_edit_btn" />
    </targets>
</fade>

<fade android:duration="400">
    <targets>
        <target android:targetId="@android:id/navigationBarBackground" />
        <target android:targetId="@android:id/statusBarBackground" />
    </targets>
</fade>
```

Comment: what is the desired behavior?

Comment: I am expecting the EditText hint also follow the animation.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `android:transitionGroup="true"` in root layout solved the problem.

e.g.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:transitionGroup="true" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

       >
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```